# Single color scale on subplot and plot.ly for R

Tags: r, graph, plotly, subplot

I'd like to generate multiple scatter plots with color scales using `plotly` and `subplot`.

```
g1 = plot_ly(
  x = runif(4), 
  y = runif(4), 
  color = runif(4), 
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers'
)
subplot(g1,g1)
```

The problem is that the color scale bar repeats for every graph, and I'd like to have a single colorbar for all graphs. Is it possible? How?

[image]

Comment: I think you can use `showscale=F`. Maybe `subplot(g1,style(g1, showscale=F))`

Comment: It would be a solution, but it is buggy. Try:

g1 = plot_ly(
  x = runif(4), 
  y = runif(4), 
  color = runif(4), 
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers'
)

g2 = plot_ly(
  x = runif(4), 
  y = runif(4), 
  color = runif(4), 
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers'
)


subplot(g2,style(g1,showscale=FALSE)) #, showscale=FALSE, showlegend = FALSE)